# mongoimport is not inserting data into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mongoimport

I have been following the mongoDB documentation to insert data into mongoDB but with no success.

Below is the command used to insert data:

`mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file primer-dataset.json`

And nothing is happening on mongod instance and I am not even getting any errors it just displays the below message and stays like that forever.

```
1969-12-31T18:00:14.000-0600    [........................] test.restaurants 0.0 B/11.3 MB (0.0%)
```

Please do help me with this.

Comment: Put your servers clock to right time! `1969-12-31T18:00:14.000-0600` and try again..